# How to iterate through multiple xml tags

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a question in regards to wanting to know how to select an element with multiple nodes?

Below is a piece of code that looks for the element 'ExtranetContract' within the first 'HotelOption' xml node:

```
def ExtranetContract = xml.'soap:Body'.xxx[0].xxx[0].xxx[0].xxx[0].xxx[0].xxx[0].@xxx

assert ExtranetContract == "false"
```

But hte xml can have multiple 'HotelOption' xml tags, so I want to go through each one and check that all 'ExtranetContract' elements within are equal to false.

How can I manipulate the code to perform this functionality?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of all the `[0]` bits as well, with:

```
def flags = xml.'soap:Body'
               .HotelAvailResponse
               .AvailabilityRS
               .Results
               .HotelResult
               .HotelOptions
               .HotelOption
               *.@ExtranetContract

assert flags.size() > 0 && flags.every { it == 'false' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work:

```
!xml.'soap:Body'.xxx[0].xxx[0].Results[0].xxx[0].xxx[0].xxx*.@xxx.contains('true')
```